# how to remove unwanted details in json

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have following classes

```
@Configurable
@Entity
public class QuestionOption {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;
    private boolean isDeleted; 
    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return isDeleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(boolean isDeleted) {
        this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
    }

    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Integer version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}


@Configurable
@Entity
public class ClientQuestionOption {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Version
@Column(name = "version")
private Integer version;

@ManyToOne
private ClientQuestion cqid;

@ManyToOne
private QuestionOption oid;
private boolean isDeleted; 
public boolean isDeleted() {
    return isDeleted;
}

public void setDeleted(boolean isDeleted) {
    this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Integer getVersion() {
    return version;
}

public void setVersion(Integer version) {
    this.version = version;
}

public ClientQuestion getCqid() {
    return cqid;
}

public void setCqid(ClientQuestion cqid) {
    this.cqid = cqid;
}

public QuestionOption getOid() {
    return oid;
}

public void setOid(QuestionOption oid) {
    this.oid = oid;
}
```

}

/////////////////////////////

```
@Configurable
@Entity
public class ClientQuestion {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Client cid;

    @ManyToOne
    private ParentQuestion pqid;

    @ManyToOne
    private QuestionType qtid;
    private boolean isDeleted; 
    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return isDeleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(boolean isDeleted) {
        this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Integer version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public Client getCid() {
        return cid;
    }

    public void setCid(Client cid) {
        this.cid = cid;
    }

    public ParentQuestion getPqid() {
        return pqid;
    }

    public void setPqid(ParentQuestion pqid) {
        this.pqid = pqid;
    }

    public QuestionType getQtid() {
        return qtid;
    }

    public void setQtid(QuestionType qtid) {
        this.qtid = qtid;
    }


}
```

//////////////////////////

```
@Configurable
@Entity
public class ParentQuestion {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Parent pid;

    @ManyToOne
    private Question qid;

    private boolean isDeleted; 

    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return isDeleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(boolean isDeleted) {
        this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Integer version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public Parent getPid() {
        return pid;
    }

    public void setPid(Parent pid) {
        this.pid = pid;
    }

    public Question getQid() {
        return qid;
    }

    public void setQid(Question qid) {
        this.qid = qid;
    }


}
```

and some more classes

I am creating a json and like this way

```
 savedQuestionOptionsList=(List<QuestionOption>)serviceClientServiceImpl.getAllSavedQuestionOptionsList(parentId , Long.valueOf(clientId) );
object.accumulate("savedQuestionOptionsList",savedQuestionOptionsList );
```

This is my service code

```
public List<QuestionOption> getAllSavedQuestionOptionsList(Long parentId,long clientId)
{
    Client client = (Client) entityManagerUtil.find(Client.class, clientId);
    List<QuestionOption>  questionsList =   (List<QuestionOption>)serviceClientDaoImpl.getAllSavedQuestionOptionsList(parentId,client);
    System.out.println("The size is nnnnnnnnnn "+questionsList.size());
    for(int i=0;i<questionsList.size();i++)
     {
 System.out.println("\n"+i+"question option listssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss");
 //System.out.println(i+"..qtid::"+questionsList.get(i).getName());
 questionsList.get(i).getName();


     }

return questionsList;
}
```

This is my dao code

```
public List<QuestionOption> getAllSavedQuestionOptionsList(Long pid,Client client)
{
    Long cid=client.getId();
    System.out.println("cid " +cid);
    System.out.println("clisnt  "+client.toString());//qt,cq,p,q
    //String queryString="SELECT distinct q FROM Question q , ParentQuestion pq ,Parent p where pq.qid.id = q.id and  p.id = pq.pid.id and q.isDeleted=false  AND p.id = "+pid+" AND (q.cid.id="+cid+" or q.cid=null)";
    String queryString="SELECT qo,cq from QuestionOption qo,ClientQuestionOption cqo,ClientQuestion cq,ParentQuestion pq,Parent p  ," +
    "Question q ,QuestionType qt     WHERE qo.id=cqo.oid.id and cqo.cqid.id=cq.id and cq.qtid.id=4 AND cq.pqid.id=pq.id AND " +
    "pq.pid.id=p.id AND pq.qid.id=q.id AND pq.pid.id=:pid AND cq.cid.id=:cid";
    Query query=entityManagerUtil.getQuery(queryString);
    query.setParameter("pid",pid);
    query.setParameter("cid",cid);
    List<QuestionOption>  questionsList =   (List<QuestionOption>)query.getResultList();
    return questionsList;

}
```

I want only the details of questionoption and ClientQuestion but the json gives details of all the entitiy classes

Please tell me how to do?

Comment: sample json http://pastie.org/9272847

Answer (score 1):

Use the `@jsonignore` annatotion, part of [jackson - springs default converter](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.1/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnore.html).

You can then just annaote you don't want to be serialzed, its nto clear from your snippets how you are performing json serialzation. But jackson is the way to go if you are using spring.